# missing “ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core)” template in Visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net, macos, visual-studio

I have Visual Studio Community for Mac,  but I don't see the ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core) template.

What should I do in this case??

Answer (score 0):

Run the installer file again and carefully make sure that ASP.NET is included in the installation options this time.

This is from an **older version** of Visual Studio, but it will look somewhat like this:

[image]